# How to use WeRelate's genealogy contest to promote Genealogy.SE

Tags: discussion, publicity

[WeRelate](http://www.werelate.org/wiki/Main_Page) runs a weekly [genealogy contest](http://www.werelate.org/wiki/Genealogy_Contest) to promote WeRelate. Is there anyway we could leverage this to promote Genealogy.SE? For example, we could ask questions on the main site about the person so the answers show up here and then contestants will find out about this site when searching for info for the contest. Do you think this is worth doing?

PS - obviously anyone interested can enter the contest themselves. And make sure to promote Genealogy.StackExchange on your WeRelate page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way through the contest itself.

But Dallan Quass is [the contact person](http://www.werelate.org/wiki/WeRelate%3aAbout) for WeRelate. [He committed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/23698/dallan-quass) to our Genealogy and Family History Q&A site back in Area 51. But he has not followed through on his committment and not signed into our site yet.

It might be worthwhile for someone who knows Dallan (maybe Justin?) to remind him that the Q&A is in beta, ask him to rejoin us, and ask if there might be any way that they could publicize our Q&A to the WeRelate users.